# xmpp_debug in libstrophe library

Tags: debugging, xmpp

How to enable the xmpp_debug in libstrophe library?
It seems like there is no seperate variable to enable and disable the debug option but I can't see trace even if add xmpp_debug at function entry itself

Comment: please help me out on this if any one is aware of libstrophe library

Answer (score 1):

In short, your task requires a proper logger:

```
int main()
{
    xmpp_log_t *log;
    xmpp_ctx_t *ctx;

    ...
    log = xmpp_get_default_logger(XMPP_LEVEL_DEBUG);
    ctx = xmpp_ctx_new(NULL, log);
    ...
}
```

With this logger every debug (and higher level) message will be printed to stderr.

---

Also, libstrophe allows to make own loggers:

```
static void my_logger(void                  *userdata,
                      const xmpp_log_level_t level,
                      const char * const     area,
                      const char * const     msg)
{
    static const char *levels[] = {
        [XMPP_LEVEL_DEBUG] = "DEBUG",
        [XMPP_LEVEL_INFO]  = "INFO",
        [XMPP_LEVEL_WARN]  = "WARN",
        [XMPP_LEVEL_ERROR] = "ERROR",
    };

    (void)userdata;
    /* This example simply prints the message to stdout. */
    printf("[%s] %s: %s\n", levels[level], area, msg);
}

int main()
{
    xmpp_log_t log = { .handler = &my_logger };
    xmpp_ctx_t *ctx;

    ...
    ctx = xmpp_ctx_new(NULL, &log);
    ...
}
```